# T-SQL LIKE regular expression

Tags: regex, t-sql, sql-like

I'm trying to select only entries in the following format from a varchar field.

[Any number of zeros][a hyphen or not][any number of numbers]

Some samples of what I want would be...

```
000000000007975
000000000-58628
123421423890347
```

But not:

```
00000--18945489
00000000000012B

SELECT Field<br>
FROM table<br>
WHERE Field LIKE ???
```

Comment: The third number in your "what I want" list doesn't match your specs. Do you mean that before the zero(es), any number of any digit is allowed?

Comment: Oh, never mind - "any" includes zero. So, next question: Is `-21374` valid?

Comment: Yeah no leading zeros is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T-SQL does not support regular expressions. You could look into the CLR to add this.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/