# How to use regular expression in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, email-validation

I'd need to have a regular expression so that I can find all invalid email addresses in our database table.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[Users] AS u 
WHERE u.EmailAddress not like 'regular expression of valid email addresses'
```

Does SQL Server support regular expressions? If so, how could I write one for email address?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229824/tsql-email-validation-without-regex

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions to validate email addresses.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression/1903368#1903368)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778362/284240

Comment: Both regular expressions in TSQL and regular expressions for validating emails have been discussed numerous times on this site. What information do you need that is not already answered elsewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL Like regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259449/tsql-like-regular-expression)

Comment: @MartinSmith I think you meant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: @AFract the two questions have been merged since

Answer (score 13):

T-SQL does not support regular expressions.  You can however create a .net CLR function that will add this ability.

This might help.
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

Comment: thanks but we have so much restriction here and we can't install assemblies into the sql server engine.

Comment: You had me there for a minute, but reading the link it looks like that will only work for the find/replace dialog in management studio, not a as part of a query :(

Comment: Unfortunately the topic given is about SQL Server **MS** rather then SQL Server engine itself

Comment: It looks like that RegEx support relates to SSMS, not to TSQL

Comment: That SQL 2012 link is just talking about regexes in SSMS -- not anything new built into SQL Server.  William, if you can't install assemblies you are not going to be able to use regexes.  You'll have to roll your own as best you can using SQL Server's intrinsic string functions.

Comment: @Joel I've proposed an idea on [SQL Server UserVoice](http://mssqlconn.uservoice.com/forums/113295-feature-feedback/suggestions/2437316-fully-support-regex-in-sql-server-engine) board